# Rails 4 local Time shown according to local time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am working on rails 4 application. I want to show the time for comment I created. If I open the site in india then time should be shown in IST (according to indian standard) and If I am in USA so for the same comment that i made in india time should be shown according to USA time zone.

What do I need to do in my config file for development and production?

Do I need to change anything in database?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails always saves times in UTC (universal time), and the server has a setting which tells it which timezone it (the server) is running in.

To show different times to the client, Rails (which runs on the server) will need to know which time zone the client is in.  This isn't in a standard request header so you will need to get them to submit the information somehow.  Once you know their timezone you can ensure that you always show times to the user using their timezone - there are helpers for this.

Getting their timezone can be done explicitly, eg by giving them a timezone dropdown in their "My Account" page, and then saving that in their user record, and/or by making it more upfront and forcing them to choose one in a popup, if you don't know it.

Or, you can do it for them using Javascript, passing it through in a cookie.  See this article for an example of how to do it.

http://thisbythem.com/blog/clientside-timezone-detection/

Comment: I like that link this by them.

Comment: Does daylight saving effect this method of getting local time zone?

Comment: Yes.  The client (browser) will get the local time from the computer's system clock, so if the computer has switched to daylight savings then that will be reflected in the timezone read by the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well one solution can be to store the time zone of the user in the database, write a filter
`around_action` in your `ApplicationController` which would set the Time.zone to the time_zone from the database field.

You might want to look at Time.zone and TimeZone in the rails api

Here is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised?view=comments) , you can figure it out from the comments and the github link.